# Checkbox cell click behaviour in Telerik RadGridView is not intuitive and requires multiple clicks

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, telerik-grid

I have bound a Telerik RadGridView properly with the first column being a bound checkbox:

```
<telerik:GridViewCheckBoxColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                Header="Generate" Width="95" IsReadOnly="False"/>
```

I can click and change the checkbox state no problem.  The problem is that checking the checkbox is not intuitive.  In order for a user to click a checkbox, they have to first click the checkbox cell, click again to activate, and then click again to check the check box.  Three individual clicks to check the checkbox.

Is there a better or native way to make this seamless?  I want the user to be able to click a checkbox and immidiately see it checked regardless if the row/cell is already selected.  I want the user to be able to do a check in one click.

Infragistics controls could do this years ago.

Could someone please explain how to get more intuitive check box behaviour in the Telerik RadGridView for Silverlight?

Comment: I do this when there is an acceptable answer...

Comment: Personally, I aim to help people regardless of any reward or recognition.  It's always worked for me.

Comment: I admire your personal philosophy, however that does not change how *this* particular community functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had much the same issue as you recently.  What I did to fix it was to put a CheckBox in the `CellTemplate` of the column:

```
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Checkbox Column" IsReadOnly="True">
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=BooleanProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Note that I've added the property `IsReadOnly="True"` to the column. This doesn't make the column read-only; you should still be able to click on the checkbox and set your boolean property.  What this property does is to prevent the cells in the column from using the `CellEditTemplate` when you click on them.

Normally, a `RadGridView` column uses the `CellTemplate` for viewing and the `CellEditTemplate` when the cell goes into edit mode.  However, we don't need to use the `CellEditTemplate` here, because the `CellTemplate` is perfectly capable of changing the value of these boolean properties on its own.

Comment: Use of a telerik:GridViewCeckBoxColumn also fixes the problem. But this answer did more than that for me. The problem I had was that the user would have to loose focus from a cell before the underlying collection was updated, but no longer, with this solution no such click away is required

Comment: So how do I make the column read only. I want to display the checks but don't want the user to be able to edit. I have binding OneWay and it still checks and unchecks when I click it

Comment: @AriesConnolly: that sounds to me as if it is a separate question. If so, please ask a separate question rather than tag it on to an answer I wrote over a decade ago. I haven't worked with Silverlight or Telerik controls for years.

Answer (score 1):

The [telerik documentation site](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/controls/radgridview/columns/how-to/checkbox-column-clicks) now has some alternatives to the approach listed in the accepted answer:

> **PROBLEM**
>
> If you have a GridViewCheckBox column to your gridview you need to
>   click three times by default in order to change the value of the
>   checkbox - the first two clicks will enter the edit mode and the last
>   one will change the value.
>
> The following solutions will give you options to control the number of
>   clicks needed to change the value of the checkbox column.
>
> **SOLUTION**
>
> First approach
>
> 2 clicks solution
>
> By setting the EditTriggers="CellClick" property of the
>   GridViewCheckBoxColumn the cells will enter edit mode with a single
>   click only. Now you will need one more click to change the value of
>   the checkbox.
>
> 1 clicks solution
>
> In addition to the EditTriggers="CellClick" property, you can set the
>   AutoSelectOnEdit="True" property of the GridViewCheckBox column. This
>   property will alter the checked state of the checkbox as soon as the
>   cell enters edit mode, thus changing the value on a single click.
>   Please note that the GridView has to be focused.
>
> This could be done in XAML or in code behind when the columns are
>   AutoGenerated:

XAML

```
<telerik:GridViewCheckBoxColumn Name="CheckBoxColumn"
            EditTriggers="CellClick"
            AutoSelectOnEdit="True"
            DataMemberBinding="{Binding IsChampion}" />
```

C#

```
private void gridView_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, GridViewAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    var dataColumn = e.Column as GridViewDataColumn;

    if (dataColumn != null)
    {
        if (dataColumn.UniqueName.ToString() == "IsChampion")
        {
            // create GridViewCheckBoxColumn
            GridViewCheckBoxColumn newColumn = new GridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            newColumn.DataMemberBinding = dataColumn.DataMemberBinding;
            newColumn.Header = dataColumn.Header;
            newColumn.UniqueName = dataColumn.UniqueName;
            newColumn.EditTriggers = Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewEditTriggers.CellClick;
            newColumn.AutoSelectOnEdit = true;
            e.Column = newColumn;
        }
    }
}
```